# Quorum private transactions - Inconsistent state

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

We are using Quorum and sending private transactions

Participant A  - Sending 3000 Private transactions to  ( Participant B and Participant c)

However, all 3000 transactions are committed successfully at Participant A. In case of Participant B and Participant C, only few transactions had gone through. Hence , the state is inconsistent across parties.

Participant A – 3000 – OK
Participant B – 487 – Inconsistent state ( EVM reverted is the error message)
Participant C – 487 – Inconsistent state ( EVM reverted is the error message)

We checked Participant B Node’s eth.syncing status and blocks syncing is fine. Also, txpool.status – both pending and queued returns 0.

Comment: Can you post the link to this on https://go-quorum.slack.com/ #technical-support channel?

Comment: I don't have access to this slack channel and I am unable to create one

Comment: I will post it for you then

Comment: @NicolasMassart did we get any reply

Comment: Could you modify your post to add a real question? You give detail about the state of your system but you don't really ask a question. For instance "how to recover state on B and C?" or "What log should I check to see what went wrong?" or "where can I get infos on the architecture I should use to prevent this?", something like that.